# Add an onClick to a submit button in React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

The Button

(this submit button is not working, and if i delete the onClick, the submit works. how can i make both, the onClick and the Submit to work.)

```
 <input
       type="submit"
       value="Make the purchase"
       onClick={nextStep}
 />
```

The whole Form

```
 <form id="my-form" className="contact-form" onSubmit={sendEmail}>
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value={shippingData.firstName} />
      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value={shippingData.lastName} />
      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value={shippingData.email} />
      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value={shippingData.address1} />
      <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="name" value={shippingData.zip} />
      <br />

      <input type="hidden" name="name" value={myJSON}></input>
      <div>
        <input
          type="submit"
          value="Make the purchase"
          onClick={nextStep}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Why can't you just perform all of your actions in the `onSubmit` handler?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What is the value of `nextStep`?  You realize, if it's a function, it needs parens, like `nextStep()`?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger This binds the handler, it's not supposed to call it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, your input button element has type submit. So when you click on it, `onSubmit` handler gets called. So if you need to do multiple things, you need multiple buttons, or do everything inside `onSubmit`

#### Option 1

Have 2 buttons:

```
 <input
    type="submit"
    value="Make the purchase"/> 

<input 
    type="button"
    value="Go to next step"
    onClick={nextStep} />
```

#### Option 2

```
<form id="my-form" className="contact-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

const handleSubmit = () => {
  nextStep()
  sendEmail()
}
```